# Mongo C#, query all documents, which array contain a specific element

Tags: c#, mongodb

How do I query in mongo all documents that contain a specific element?

```
public class House
{
    public Room [] Rooms {get; set;}
}

public class Room 
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

I need to build a filter that filter all houses with "bathroom", because I want to set the price of the bathroom to X.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code should do you what you want:

```
var collection = database.GetCollection<House>("houses");
collection.Find(new FilterDefinitionBuilder<House>().ElemMatch(house => house.Rooms, room => room.Name == "bathroom"));
```